# Modular Arithmetic and repeated exponentiation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, tetration

I was messing around with mod and repeated exponentiation and noticed that if we let $P_n(k)$ denote repeated exponentiation by $n$, $k$ times then,

$$\text{mod} \ b : a^{P_n(k)} \equiv a^{P_n(k-1)} \equiv a^{P_n(k-2)} \equiv \cdots \equiv a^{P_n(1)}=a^n.$$

Which however, isn't true if I let $k$ go to $0$.

For example,

$$\text{mod} \ 7 : 40^{3^{3^{3^{3}}}} \equiv 40^{3^{3^3}} \equiv 40^{3^3} \equiv 40^3 \equiv 6$$

Is this true in general? For any values of $a,b,n,k$ for which it is defined? I tried proving this by induction but was unsuccessful, but if possible it is preferable that the proof is not done by induction since induction doesn't exactly explain $\textbf{why}$ something is true.

EDIT: Noticing a couple of cases where it isn't true namely in the comments, I edit my question to.
For which $a,b,n,k$ is this true?

Comment: For example, $2^{2^{2}} = 2^4 = 16 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$, $2^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$

Comment: Well, it seems to work in some specific cases so, when is it true? Since it seems to work for 40, 3 and 7, for a while at least, and 50, 7 and 8. There seem to be cases where it is true. I'll add on an additional edit taking this into account.

Comment: $(50, 7, 8)$ case can be also explained; $50^7 = 2^7 \cdot N$ for some $N$ integer, and $8 | 2^7$ so they are all 0 $\pmod 8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, one can see that $a^n\bmod b$ is eventually periodic in $n$. Let $a^{n+b'}\equiv a^n$ for sufficiently large $n$. Then the problem boils down to finding $n\bmod b'$.

By similar arguments, one can furthermore show that $n^k\bmod b'$ is eventually periodic in $k$ for $k<b'$. By induction, this let's us push a $\bmod$ up the power tower, until eventually we reach $\bmod1$, which gives us $0$. At such a point, additional powers only contribute to reaching the point where we reach that "eventually periodic" step.

Conclusion:

> $a^{P_n(k)}\bmod b$ is eventually constant in $k$. What you are observing is the special case when it starts being constant at $k=1$.

Additional note:

Euler's totient and Carmichael's functions gives a $\bmod$ that gets pushed up into the next power (although it may not be optimal), so repeatedly applying $\varphi$ or $\lambda$ to the initial $b$ gives you a maximum height to check. For example, when $b=7$ and with Euler's totient function, we have

$\varphi(7)=6$

$\varphi(6)=2$

$\varphi(2)=1$

which means we only have to manually check $k<3$. For $a=40$ and $n=3$, it happens to be the case, so it holds for all $k\ge1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $40 \equiv 5 \pmod7$, and $5^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$. (Fermat)

Each of $3$, $3^3$, $3^{3^3}, \cdots$ are multiple of $3$ and is not even, so they are all of the form $6k+3$. This leads to $40^{3^{3^\cdots}} \equiv 5^3 \equiv 6 \pmod 7$.

I think one could find more pattern like this; Let $b$ odd prime, $n = (b-1)/2$, $a$ be comprime to $b$.

Comment: This question originally sprouted from the fact that $3^{3^{\cdots}}$ is congruent to less iterated powers under mod $10^k$, where $k$ is the $k$ in $P_n(k)$, can something be done for this as well? Sorry, I understand your argument but I don't really get how to extend it to other cases. In other words all $3^[P_3(m)}$ has the same $k$ digits as $3^{P_3{k}}$, where $m \geq k$

Comment: I'm sorry; odd condition is not sufficient. $b$ should be prime of the form $4k+3$. With this (additional) condition we can proceed with same steps; $n^{n^\cdots}$ is odd and is multiple of $n$. so it is congruent with $n \pmod{b-1}$. $a^{b-1} \equiv 1 \pmod {b}$ by Fermat Little theorem.

Comment: Let me think of the explation with $10^k$ thing.

Comment: This is also explained as follows; the following $5^{10} = 5^{100} = 5^{1000} = \cdots \equiv 2\pmod7$ holds. $5^{10..0}  = 5\cdot 5^{9..9} = 5\cdot 5^{6k + 3}$ for some integer $k$. And again $5^6  \equiv 1\pmod 7 $.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this explains the $10^k$ thing?